# Change keyword highlighting in R knitr in LaTeX

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, syntax-highlighting

I am using R's `knitr` package to document some code in LaTeX (to PDF) using Lyx.  I have the highlight option turned on in my code chunks, but am trying to understand how to go about changing the keywords that are highlighted in my code chunks.  Is there an easy way I can add additional keywords or change which words are have which colors?  I tried reviewing some of the documentation, but I couldn't quite figure this out.

Here is an example of what I have in document:

```
\begin{document}

<<MyOptions, echo=FALSE>>=
knit_theme$set("biogoo")
@


<<CodeExplanation, highlight=TRUE, eval=FALSE, size="small">>=
#define SITE 1232
#define YEAR "2017"
#define PHASE "8"
<more code is here>
@

\end{document}
```

Note that the code inside my chunk is not R code, but I'm just using the code chunks to document some piece of proprietary code in another proprietary language.  I've explored using knitr's language option, but it's a bit more advanced than I'm comfortable with at this point, but I'd be open to using it if I understood how to use it more.

**So, is there a simple way I can gain control over additional keyword highlighting within R knitr?**

Comment: If you read about [`knitr` options, code-decoration](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-decoration), it references the [`highlight`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highlight/index.html) package. There are some comments in the [package `README.md`](https://github.com/romainfrancois/highlight#readme).

Comment: I've read through all of these and still can't seem to get this to work.  In fact, I even tried `engine='highlight' engine.opts='-S awk -O latex'` as demonstrated on page 123 of Yihui's Dynamic Dcouments with R and knitr, 2nd, and nothing seems to work.  I wonder if this is bug where something is now broken compared to when the book was initially written?

Comment: I don't to, to be honest. If @YihuiXie doesn't have an immediate answer, you might consider raising an issue to indicate incorrect behavior based on your efforts.

Comment: Which error do you get with `engine = 'highlight'`? Do you have the [`highlight` *program*](https://gitlab.com/saalen/highlight) installed? On Debian (derived) you can get it via `sudo apt-get install highlight`.

Comment: I didn't think we had to install `highlight` since there is already a `highlight` package in R that I have installed.  But just in case, I did install `highlight` and tried to run the code, but I am still unable to get the expected results.  I just get the error in my pdf output "Error in running command highlight."

Comment: What is the output of `Sys.which("highlight")`? Which OS do you use? BTW, once there is more than one commenter you should @-mention whom you are replying to.